# receiving error message while trying to register for subscription for rhel6

Tags: linux, rhel

I am trying to subscribe to redhat from the terminal. I have registered an account at https://access.redhat.com/labs/registrationassistant/ . So I am using those credentials to register my subscription.

But I don't understand, even after following the instructions why I couldn't register for the subscription?

```
[root@server /]# subscription-manager register
username:xxx
password:abc
xxx cannot register with any organizations.
```

and when I am entering my mailID in the username's place I am receiving an error as : **The system is unable to complete the requested transaction**

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: when I am executing subscription-manager status, the output is as follows :
Overall Status : Unknown